# How do i check a date value falls with in a date range last month

Tags: php

How do i check a date value falls with in a date range of last month using PHP ?

For example : `2015-09-12` is a date in last Month. But `2015-08-15 is not`.

Thanks,
Sumesh

Comment: echo date("Y-n-j", strtotime("first day of previous month"));  You can do like this

Comment: ...and you tried some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
date('mm', strtotime('2015-09-12')) === date('mm', strtotime(' - 1 MONTH'));
```

Will be `true` if date falls in last month else `false`